# Why can't I look at 'individual' relationship on contact/lead?

Tags: security, gdpr

In order to comply with GDPR rules and regulations, I've enabled the 'Individual' object in our org to store individual's privacy preferences. Our main use case is to prevent any type of Data Loader job that would alter or add a contact/lead with the same email as an individual in our system when the 'shouldForget' checkbox = true.

I am currently trying to test this use case in sandbox. However, I can't seem to get the Individual lookup field on the contact and lead to show up when I run reports.

Is there a way to make this relationship visible from a reporting perspective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that to work by creating a custom Report Type and add fields related via lookup in the Field Layout Properties. Then recreate your report based on the custom Report Type.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes I already had created a report type. What I forgot to do was bring the Individual object a visible field for the custom report type.